# Active Model Serializers pagination links not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using the instructions here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

I have an initializer file with:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

(restarted the server to initialize)

In my model I have:

```
def packages
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @records = @user.get_records("api").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
    render json: @records
end
```

My response is as follows and is not showing the links block:

```
[
  {
    created_at: "2016-04-07T18:24:03.216Z",
    title: "Record 1"
  },
  {
    created_at: "2016-03-07T18:24:43.245Z",
    title: "Record 2"
  },
  {
    created_at: "2016-02-07T18:22:33.236Z",
    title: "Record 3"
  }
]
```

I can see in my server log that it's using will_paginate:

```
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with WillPaginate::Collection (0.13ms)
```

Any ideas why I'm not seeing the links?

### Update:

I am paginating an array with will_paginate, therefore I added require 'will_paginate/array' in the controller.
When I try to follow the second method of creating the dictionary in the controller like so...

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ActionController::Base
  require 'will_paginate/array'
  def packages
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @records = @user.get_records("api").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
      render json: @records, 
      meta: pagination_dict(@records)
  end
    def pagination_dict(object)
    {
      current_page: object.current_page,
      next_page: object.next_page,
      prev_page: object.prev_page,
      total_pages: object.total_pages,
      total_count: object.total_count
    }
  end
end
```

Then I get:

```
undefined method `prev_page' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x007fced3698d78> Did you mean? previous_page per_page
```

Which I find also strange.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing the whole response and not just its `:data` part (i.e. `response[:data]`)? The API should never return just an array of hashes but a hash with `:data`, `:links`, etc. as documented [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/jsonapi/schema.md#success-document).

Comment: positive, and yes, I find it strange too.

Comment: Ah, for will_paginate it will be `previous_page`  instead of `prev_page` and `total_entries` instead of `total_count`. Interesting that this style seems to work but the main one doesn't.

Comment: Oh, missed that, however, I fixed it and it still doesn't print the links in the response. No data, no meta.

Answer (score 0):

The function `pagination_dict(object)` should be in your Base controller and not in the Users Controller